# CSS for pre and code tags not working on mobile device

Tags: html, css, blogger

I have a blog and I wish to insert a code block inside my post using simple <pre> and <code> tags using CSS.

```css
pre code {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

It's working well in desktop view but it's not working on my mobile phone (especially for elements: background, border, overflow, and display). What did I do wrongly? I'm expecting the code block will be seen as in the desktop view.

Here are the outputs both in desktop view and mobile view: [The Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDpQe.jpg) and [The Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyIr1.jpg)

Comment: Can you show the output in mobile view?

Comment: Hi, I have added the output above.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using a third-party blog website? Maybe your blog website is applying styling to narrow viewports (such as mobile devices) that is overriding your CSS. Use Developer Tools in your desktop browser to see what happens at narrow breakpoints.

If your CSS is applied from an external stylesheet, maybe your phone browser is using a cached CSS file.

```css
pre code {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<pre>
  <code>
    pre code {
      background-color: #eee;
      border: 1px solid #999;
      display: block;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: auto;
    }
  </code>
</pre>
```